# Margin is not working in Specific div content

Tags: css, magento

Hello I am new in designing  and I I want to set the div sequence But When I give margin to the specific div it apply to all div I used unique class but problem is same

[here is link of site](http://soho.breadtest.com/binwarehouse/)

[image]

I want align special offers like express shipping

Comment: try adding <div class="subtitle">blah blah blah</div> for special offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another property (display: flex;) in your css for .footer-top-inner.container-width (DIV containing your blocks)

```
<div class="footer-top-inner container-width">
    //your footerblocks
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer-top-inner.container-width{
    display: flex;
    //if that doesn't work, you might want to use display: flex !important;
}
```

But the best way would be to add another class to this container, just to prevent our override messing your website :)

EDIT: To keep your website looking good, you can add another property within display: flex;

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

This should automatically align your footerblocks

Comment: To add to this, you can use `.footerblock1 .title {margin-top: 8px;}` to vertically center the text next to the image.